# How can I sort files based on date modified in Java and copy to the respective folder

Tags: java, file, sorting

Like if date modified is 31/12/1999 then it should be copied to 1999->12->31

I’m saving the files in a collection and looping over each element and inner loops to create a path help me copy the files.

I’m saving month day and date in separate collections
and nested loops to create files based on day month and year.

```
File [] files = dir.listFiles(); //im listing files here

 LinkedHashSet<Integer> yyyy =new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
 LinkedHashSet<Integer> mm =new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
 LinkedHashSet<Integer> dd =new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
 LinkedHashSet<Long> date =new LinkedHashSet<Long>();
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

 for(File sl:files)
 {
     c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
     c.setTimeInMillis(sl.lastModified());

    int year= c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day= c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month= c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    //System.out.println(year);
    //System.out.println(day);
    //System.out.println(mm);
    //System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    yyyy.add(year);
    mm.add(month);
    dd.add(day);

for(int i:yyyy)
{
    new File(dest+"/"+i).mkdirs();
    for(int j:mm)
    {
        if(i==year&&j==month)
        {
        new File(dest+"/"+i+"/"+j).mkdirs();
        }

        for(int k:dd)
        {
            if(i==year&&j==month&&k==day)
            {
                new File(dest+"/"+i+"/"+j+"/"+k).mkdirs();//creating folders here

            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working here? Code looks correct, just incomplete.

Comment: i created the structire i need help with copying the files

Comment: See this article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-file

Comment: can you just give me the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Apache Commons IO` library's `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` to copy the file.

```
FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
```

This is a simple method to copy the file. There are other/optimized ways to copy the files also, which you can find on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sort your files that are now in a folder by their last modified date by creating a hierarchically structured folders and subfolders with year, month and date.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class NewClass7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File("C:/path_to_yor_dir/");
        File [] files = dir.listFiles(); 
        //Create a function that returns a LocalDate for a given file by converting the lastModifided atribute to LocalDate
        Function<File,LocalDate> func = f -> LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(f.lastModified()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        //Create a map by grouping your files by date with the function above
        Map<LocalDate, List<File>> map = Stream.of(files).filter(File::isFile).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(func));
        for(LocalDate d: map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(d);
            //create a directorie for each found year, month and date
            Path target = Paths.get("C:/path_to_yor_dir/" + d.getYear() + "/" + d.getMonthValue() + "/" + d.getDayOfMonth());
            Files.createDirectories(target);
            for(File f: map.get(d)){
                    System.out.println(f);
                    Path from = f.toPath();
                    //copy files or use Files.move(...) if you want to move them
                    Files.copy(from, target.resolve(f.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```